# Datasource method is not called in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UICollection with only one section.

My issue is that my datasource method :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is never called when I init the UICollection. And I return a valid number  (3) into the following datasource method !

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

After checking with breakpoints, my number of items in section 0 is returned, but still the `numberOfItemsInSection` method isn't called.

Any Idea ?

I precise that I've already make 6 UICollection in my app with exactly the same frame but not the same data; I don't know why, this doesn't work this time.

Comment: check if you have set the datasource in your storyboard i missed it a few times in my apps.

Comment: Cell registered? Cell size? Does the collectionView can show a cell? In other words, it may be possible that the cell to show is "hidden" (outside the frame but in the content size).

Comment: My cell can't be displayed because the method `numberOfItemsInSection ` is not called. The cell size is based on a layout and the layout works with other UICollectionView...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'm an idiot. I forgot : `[self.view addSubview: myCollectionView];`

Thanks for help....

Comment: You're not. Trust me, with the sheer number of methods that Apple unload on to us each year... It's about time Xcode auto implemented empty protocol methods.. That's save us a WHOLE lot of pain!